# dropdown list with 2 values

Tags: php

I need to create a dropdownlist which has two values "OK" and "NOK" one should be selected by default based of an value of $Status. The user should than be able to change the selection or let the default one. How can i manage this? What i have tried:

```
<select name="Status">
  <option value="OK">OK selected="selected"</option>
  <option value="NOK">NOK</option>
</select>
```

Comment: post what you have tried

Comment: check select tag in html, it has default option too. And Down vote for lack of trying.

Comment: Have you attempted to solve this problem on your own? If you just Google "html option selected by default," you will find a bunch of information on how this can be done.

Comment: Basic HTML coding with one PHP if...else construction. Search!

Comment: yes it tried it with different examples from google

Comment: No offense, but if I had enough Rep to do so, I would have voted this down as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<select>
  <option value="OK" <?php if($Status == "OK") echo 'selected="selected"';?>>OK</option>
  <option value="NOK" <?php if($Status == "NOK") echo 'selected="selected"';?>>NOK</option>
</select>
```

You can add an id and/or name attribute to the select as you like.

Comment: I know had to wait 4 mintues.